# How to make this code use async and await?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I am just begining to learn async and await. How do I make this code below work with async/await? It compiles only if I remove the await keyword.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AsyncExperiment();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void AsyncExperiment()
        {
              //var t1 =  Task.Run(() => LongProcess()); //ok
              var t2= await  Task.Run(()=>LongProcess()); //compile time error

        }


        private static void LongProcess()
        {
            //a call to some slow service
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Async is not useful for console apps like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other than `LongProcess` being `void`, the `await` keyword is missing the `async` keyword which needs to come in the method signature:

```
private static async void AsyncExperiment()
```

A couple of things to note:

1. `async void` is ment only for top level event handlers. Instead, use `async Task` when you have a void returning method
2. [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx), The answer is usually no. You should think about why you need to wrap this method in a `Task.Run`. I know this is an attempt to test the `Task Parallel Library`, but you should keep that in mind. Let the consumer of your synchronous method use `Task.Run` instead.
3. If your work is IO bound, like calling a web service, there is usually no need to use a ThreadPool thread. For example, if your service is using REST, you can use the `HttpClient` library which exposes asynchronous methods (`GetAsync`, `PostAsync`, etc..). With async, really, [There Is No Thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

Answer (score 3):

`LongProcess()` is a method that returns `void`.

Just like you can't expect this to work:

```
var result = LongProcess();
```

You cannot expect this to work:

```
var result = await Task.Run(() => LongProcess());
```

`Task.Run()` as used here returns a `Task` (that has no result).  Just call it without assigning to anything.

```
await Task.Run(() => LongProcess());
```